# Why a reduced over match is considered an ODI match?

Tags: rules, cricket, interruption

We see matches are reduced to certain amount of overs due to bad whether conditions like rain, bad lights etc.

For example the rain affected the match between [IND vs ENG in Champions Trophy](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-champions-trophy-2013/content/story/644431.html) final was reduced to 20 overs per side.

Why is it still considered an ODI match?

Comment: I feel that this question, in its initial form, is slightly unclear. Such a match is still an ODI because the ODI regulations allow the overs to be reduced. Turning it round: why should a reduced-over match not be considered an ODI?

Comment: because when a match is reduced the rules for power play and maximum number of overs a bowler can bowl will also be changed.But if considered your comment the **Such a match is still an ODI because the ODI regulations allow the overs to be reduced**.I think it is more clear to understand why the match will be called an ODI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In One Day International matches the number of overs is 50 per side. In the situation of interruption due to rain, a method named [Duckworth–Lewis method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duckworth%E2%80%93Lewis_method) is applied. So that we can get the result of the match **by reducing some overs**. As per [DL method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duckworth%E2%80%93Lewis_method#Application) the minimum number of overs to be played per side is 20. So if an ODI match is reduced to 20 overs, it is still considered as an ODI match. To clarify more, this method is used even before T20 matches came in cricket. (i.e. that's why such matches are not considered as T20I matches.)

Comment: I guess that they probably are _also_ not considered T20 matches, because T20 matches have [different rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty20#General_rules) than ODI matches. Also, there's a different approach towards the tie (I think there's no tie under DL, only a target).

Comment: @aufkag - Did you mean result after the match is tied (i.e. super over)? Such rules depend on the tournaments. Also, the match [can be tied](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-india-2011/engine/match/474480.html) even after the DL method is applied. :-)

Comment: My understanding _was_ that D/L provides a target only. If you reach it, you win. If you don't, you lose. But your counterexample shows that I must have been wrong. Good point. I'm more confused than ever. :) Actually, not so sure, given that the match ended in rain. Draw??

Comment: Ignore that last sentence. Looking it up now.

Comment: Ah, in your Wikipedia link: "If the second team _passes_ the target, then the second team is taken to have won the match; if the match ends when the second team has exactly met (but not passed) the target (rounded down to the next integer) then the match is taken to be a tie." So, you seem to be right, and I seem to be wrong. Strange to call it target, but hey, apparently they do. (And this was _not_ how it was explained to me.)

Comment: The reason of my confusion also lies in the fact that _we_ usually set the "target" at "1st innings"+1 on the scoreboard. But at our level we don't play according to D/L.

Comment: @aufkag Yes, the D/L method always first involves the calculation of the score to tie, rather than to win; one run is then added to yield the target. South Africa famously [crashed out of the 2003 World Cup](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdenalmanack/content/story/155875.html) after making that very mistake, believing they needed 229 to win under D/L, when 229 was actually the [score to tie](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/65272.html).

Comment: @Spinner I comfort myself by being, although wrong, in good company. :) Although you reintroduce a wrong definition of target under D/L, it seems.

Comment: @aufkag The Wikipedia article uses the term _target_ inconsistently. In one paragraph it's used (correctly) to refer to the score to win; in the next it's incorrectly used to refer to the score to tie. Best to refer to the [official ICC D/L method document](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/518a6ddb1aaf6-Duckworth_Lewis%20Method.pdf)!

Comment: @Spinner So, I was right in one respect (the meaning of target), but definately wrong in that I didn't know that target-1 is always a tie. (Right?) Thanks.